# create shapes with css

Tags: html, css

```css
.shape {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 30px;
    transform: skewX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">Hello World!</div>
```

We have two following shapes in `jpg` format. But on certain condition background and border color needs to change to some different color. So idea is to create those images with CSS transform Property (if possible).

```
{   width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 30px;
    transform: skewX(0);
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could also go with SVGs and then use CSS to apply styles.

Comment: Hey, you've said you have two shapes in jpeg format and want to recreate them in CSS, but you haven't shown us the jpegs

Comment: @Scoots sorry, Just added

Comment: Try to replicate the "issue" with the appropriate snippet.

Comment: do you want to change the color of image??? in css??????

Comment: On certain scenario I want to change the colour of shape but since it is the image I can't do it. that's why I want to create those shape using HTML CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using SVG

```css
.a {
  fill: #ef0c4d;
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke-width: 7px;
}

.a:hover {
  fill: green;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 680.4 240.3">
<path class="a" d="M135,113.1s7.7,123.6,13.5,164.4c6.3,44.5,13,64,168,64h490L737.7,184.3a5.6,5.6,0,0,0-4.2-3.2L140.1,108.2A4.5,4.5,0,0,0,135,113.1Z" transform="translate(-131.4 -104.7)"/>
</svg>
```

---

Using CSS

```css
.rect {
    width: 230px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.rect:before {
  content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #dedede;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 26px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
}

.rect:after {
  content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #dedede;
    transform: rotate(10deg) skew(30deg);
    bottom: 20px;
    left: -38px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```

Comment: First of all thanks. I ask for one solution you gave me two. Can you give me more information about how did you measure the path for SVG. Any tool

Comment: @Carlos You can use the free tool inkscape [link](https://inkscape.org/en/)

Comment: @Carlos If u have adobe subscribtion, then use illustrator,Both tools will allow export to svg. Then u can copy paste the svg code into html

Comment: @Carlos if this answer help u, then please accept it

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier to go with SVG than pure CSS, here is an example:

```css
path {
    fill:pink;
}
path:hover {
  fill:red;
  stroke:#000;
}
```

```html
<svg
  xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
  viewBox='0 0 64 64'
  width='200' >
  <path d='M18 48 L56 48 L46 30 L12 16 C8 14 8 16 8 18 L8 40 C8 44 10 48 14 48 Z' />
</svg>
```

You may consider this link to easily adjust the shape [`http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M18 48 L56 48 L46 30 L12 16 C8 14 8 16 8 18 L8 40 C8 44 10 48 14 48 Z`](http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M18%2048%20L56%2048%20L46%2030%20L12%2016%20C8%2014%208%2016%208%2018%20L8%2040%20C8%2044%2010%2048%2014%2048%20Z)

Answer (score -1):

What are the 'certain conditions'? If you wanted to change the image color on hover with pure CSS an easy way would be to set the image as a background of a div element. You would then create a second identical image (with new color) to change to.

HTML -

```
<div id="color-1"></div>
```

and the CSS

```
#color-1 {
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background-image:url('some/image/path');
}

 #color-1:hover {
    background-image:url('some-other/image/path');
}
```